# How drag and drop text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to create a message template as follows,

> Hello Stackoverflow {Text A} Thank you for your support {Text B}

[image]

In that case, I need to use drags and drop fields to `Textarea`, I did initial R&D to find some library to achieve my requirement and found this [Inserting text with drag n’ drop](http://skfox.com/jqExamples/insertAtCaret.html)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#ClickWordList li').click(function() { 
    $("#txtMessage").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
    return false
  });
  $("#DragWordList li").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
  $(".txtDropTarget").droppable({
    accept: "#DragWordList li",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(this).insertAtCaret(ui.draggable.text());
    }
  });
});

$.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
  return this.each(function(){
  //IE support
  if (document.selection) {
    this.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;
    this.focus();
  }
  //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
  else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
    var startPos = this.selectionStart;
    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
    this.focus();
    this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  } else {
    this.value += myValue;
    this.focus();
  }
  });
};
```

**Html**

```
<body>
    <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="navtoplistline">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="maincolumn">
                <div class="text">
                    <h2>Message #1</h2>
                    <textarea name="txtMessage" id="txtMessage" class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable" cols="80" rows="15"></textarea>
                    <h2>Message #2</h2>
                    <textarea name="txtMessage2" id="txtMessage2" class="txtDropTarget ui-droppable" cols="80" rows="15"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Click to insert:</legend>
                <ul id="ClickWordList">
                    <li>Hello world!</li>
                    <li>All your base</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Drag to insert:</legend>
                <ul id="DragWordList">
                    <li class="ui-draggable">Hello world!</li>
                    <li class="ui-draggable">All your base</li>
                    <li class="ui-draggable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

This works fine, ***but I only need to click the field and add clicked item to `Textarea` (no need drag and drop option), and also need to remove added filed from Textarea by clicking cross sign. How can I do it, please help me to solve this***. The above example is not clear for me to implement my requirement. so please help me to solve this.

**Update:** As Twisty says cannot implement `X` inside Textarea what can I use instead of it? any suggestion?

Comment: You can remove the Draggable and Drop calls. In regards to an `x` or close button, this cannot be done inside a TextArea.

Comment: @Twisty can you please suggest a solution to `x` and close option? and please give me an answer to remove the draggable option and only clickable option, please give me a answer sir,please

Comment: There is not a easy way to do this. I would look at TinyMCE or something like that where you could add templates of text: https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/